# How to save the url in android WebView

Tags: java, android

For example, a user opens the app for the first time and sends them to the main page. Lets say www.youtube.com(**as the homepage for the app**) as an example. Then they click on a video(now its a different url). Then they close the app(completely) then the user later runs the app again. Instead of going to www.youtube.com again(the apps homepage), **I want to load the url where the user left at**.

**Note:** For new users it should send them to the homepage.

*Thats just an example, I have my own homepage URL, see MainActivity.java code below. 
I'm new to app development and rusty with coding.

**MainActivity.java class**

```
   package name.anime;

   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.view.WindowManager;
   import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
   import android.webkit.WebSettings;
   import android.webkit.WebView;
   import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

   import cpr.name.videoenabledwebview.R;

   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity   
   {

    private VideoEnabledWebView webView;
    private VideoEnabledWebChromeClient webChromeClient;
    private String currentUrl;
    private String orgUrl = "https://kissanime.to/M";
    private boolean urlChange = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Save the web view
        webView = (VideoEnabledWebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        //WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        //webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Initialize the VideoEnabledWebChromeClient and set event handlers
        View nonVideoLayout = findViewById(R.id.nonVideoLayout); // Your own view, read class comments
        ViewGroup videoLayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.videoLayout); // Your own view, read class comments
        //noinspection all
        View loadingView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.content_main, null); // Your own view, read class comments


        webChromeClient = new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient(nonVideoLayout, videoLayout, loadingView, webView) // See all available constructors...
        {
            // Subscribe to standard events, such as onProgressChanged()...
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                // Your code...
            }
        };
        webChromeClient.setOnToggledFullscreen(new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient.ToggledFullscreenCallback() {
            @Override
            public void toggledFullscreen(boolean fullscreen) {
                // Your code to handle the full-screen change, for example showing and hiding the title bar. Example:
                if (fullscreen) {
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
                    attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                    attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
                        //noinspection all
                        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
                    }
                } else {
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
                    attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                    attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
                        //noinspection all
                        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);

        // *******Original Url(HOMEPAGE, for first time)******
        webView.loadUrl(orgUrl);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String url=prefs.getString(orgUrl, ""); //Don't know what values are used for here
        webView.loadUrl(url);

    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // Notify the VideoEnabledWebChromeClient, and handle it ourselves if it doesn't handle it
        if (!webChromeClient.onBackPressed())
        {
            if (webView.canGoBack())
            {
                webView.goBack();
            }
            else
            {
                // Standard back button implementation (for example this could close the app)
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Heres my other class **MyAppWebViewclient.java** that can be used.

**MyAppWebViewclient.java**

```
    package name.anime;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    /**
    * Created by Marvin on 1/16/2016.
     */
    public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        Context myContext;

        public MyAppWebViewClient(Context context)
        {
           this.myContext = context;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url {
            if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("kissanime.to")) {
                  return false;

            }else {

             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
             view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
             return true;

            }
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
          // do your stuff here

         SharedPreferences prefs =          PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(myContext.getApplicationContext());
         SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
         edit.putString("https://kissanime.to/M", url);
         edit.commit();



     }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In method OnPageFinished in your MyAppWebViewClient. Save url into SharePreference.
Then when re open app check if SharePreference is not empty. using

```
webview.loadurl(URL)
//URL get from SharePreference
```

Please add onPageFinished same below here:

```
 /**
         * Created by Marvin on 1/16/2016.
        */
 public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

     @override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // Save url to SharePreference
        }

     @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("kissanime.to")) {
            return false;

        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering Duc, But i'm not understanding what you mean. I do not have the method OnPageLoaded, unless if I have to create one and how do I save the url  into SharePreference? thanks.

Comment: Please open  MyAppWebViewClient.java in webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient()); and implement onPageLoaded method

Comment: I'm reall sorry but I'm still working on my java skills. I still do not understand what you mean. Here is the MyAppWebViewClient class:

Comment: I'm sorry. This method is onPageFinished(). My mistake. I edited your class

Comment: Ok, I've created, public void onPageFinished() method. Whats next? thank you for helping me.

Comment: I do not know what to add in the method... Like i said, My java programming is rusty and I'm trying to make this app to improve my skills.

Comment: I edit my answer. Please check. Did you know to use SharePreference?

Comment: No, I'm new to android development. i saw the method but i do not know what to do next.

Comment: please use this class: http://pastebin.com/W2svz1i4 and change   webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient()); to   webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient(this));

Comment: Thanks so much Duc! :) I'll try this and see if it works.

Comment: On my MainActivity.java should this code be present? --->         webView.loadUrl(orgUrl);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String url=prefs.getString(orgUrl, "");
        webView.loadUrl(url);

Comment: Look at my code above on MainActivity.java. Under my ----> // *******Original Url(HOMEPAGE, for first time)****** comment

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesnt work :'(. When i open the app, the website doesnt load. It's just a blank screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Ive updated the code above to your new class you gave me

Comment: Please look at classes above *Not the answers code* Go to very top, I hope you can still help. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I'll let you when, I'll send you a link. Thanks